# Check each column and row for duplicate

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to check if Latin square is true by user input. But I can't figure out how to do the check part, where it checks each column and row for duplicate numbers.

This is what I came up with, but it doesn't seem to work properly:

```
// arr= input by user in array, and n= array length by user input     
bool latin(int**arr,int n)
    {
      int times=0;
      int s;

        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
            for(int i=0; i<n;i++){

                if (arr[i][j]==s) times++;

            }
        }

    if (times != 1) return false;
    else return true;
    }
```

Comment: You came up with a rather random code, so no wonder it doesn't "work properly". I suggest you first sit down with a pen and piece of paper, and formulate the algorithm yourself in the human language - imagine you have a very obedient, but rather unsophisticated servant, and you are explaining the task to them as a sequence of steps they must perform. Than try to translate this to the programming language. There is also a useful technique called https://rubberduckdebugging.com/

Comment: So what exactly is `s`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to pass a single dimension array:

```
bool latin(int const * const arr, unsigned int capacity)
{
  int counter = 0;
  int s; // Please initialize this.
  for (int row = 0; row < MAXIMUM_ROWS; ++row)
  {
    for (int column = 0; column < MAXIMUM_COLUMNS; ++column)
    {
       const int value = *(arr + row * MAXIMUM_COLUMNS + column);
       if (value == s) // Remember s is not initialized.
       {
         ++counter;
       }
    }
  }
  return counter == 1;
}
```

In the above code, the slot in the array is accessed by the formula:

```
value = *(arr + row * MAXIMUM_COLUMNS + column);
```

The compiler will generate the similar code for accessing a 2 dimensional array, provided that you specify the number of columns, such as `(int arr[][MAXIMUM_COLUMNS], int capacity)`.  Because a 2 dimensional array is allocated as a large one dimensional array in memory.